# Java, Eclipse. How to allow a scanner to read both lower and uppercase?

Tags: java, eclipse, java.util.scanner, uppercase, lowercase

first I want to say you guys are wonderful. I've learned a lot from all of you. My question is how can I allow my scanner to read both upper and lower case inputs from the user?? my code is as follows.

```
Scanner anotherScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean usersSelection = false;
String c;
while (!usersSelection) {
    System.out.println("Selection: ");
    if (anotherScanner.hasNext("q")) {
        c = anotherScanner.next();
        usersSelection = true;
        System.out.println("you have selected to quit");
    }
    if (anotherScanner.hasNext("t")) {
        c = anotherScanner.next();
        usersSelection = true;
        System.out.println("you have selected the coin toss estimator");
    }
    if (anotherScanner.hasNext("g")) {
        c = anotherScanner.next();
        usersSelection = true;
        System.out.println("you have selected the grade estimator");
    }
    if (anotherScanner.hasNext("c")) {
        c = anotherScanner.next();
        usersSelection = true;
        System.out.print("You have selected color Challenge");
    } else {
        String zoom = anotherScanner.next();
        System.out.println("You have entered an invalid option. '"
            + zoom + "' is not a valid option.");
    }
}
```

I would like to carry on operations depending on user's choice(case-insenitive), i.e. whether user enters "Q" or "q".

Comment: Are you saying that your scanner does not distinguish between upper and lower case? It should automatically do that

Comment: I think they're saying they want `hasNext("x")` to be case insensitive.

Comment: `Scanner` supports regular expression, so something like `anotherScanner.hasNext("q|Q")` might work

Comment: Might work?  Might work?  @MadProgrammer, what you mean to say is "will work".  Assuming that's what OP is actually asking, of course.  That's the part that's open to debate.

Comment: When I run the program, and it prompts me to select (g,c,t,q) if I enter, for example, c it will read "You have selected color challenge." But if I enter C (capitalized) it reads "You have entered an invalid option. My question is how can I make the scanner ignore the case or convert the users input to read it as if it were capitalized?

Comment: @DavidWallace Wanted to test it before committing to the statement ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Very wise.  Now, if you'd like to turn your comment into an answer, I could probably see fit to give you an upvote.

Comment: Haha, you were too quick for me!  +1.

Comment: Thank you MadProgrammer, you've solved my issue, however do you know how exactly I would do this using the String method toUpperCase?

Comment: See, I would have just written `anotherScanner.next()` at the top of the loop, then called `toLowerCase()` and passed it to a `switch/case` statement.

Comment: You can also use the regex `(?i)q` rather than `q|Q`.

Answer (score 4):

Scanner supports regular expression, so you could use someting like `anotherScanner.hasNext("q|Q")` instead

Answer (score 2):

Change to this,

1).

```
anotherScanner.hasNext("q") || anotherScanner.hasNext("Q")
```

2).

```
anotherScanner.hasNExt("q|Q");
```

Implemenet anyone.